# Reverting edit that makes an answer worse, but was within the 5 minute update window

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, grace-period

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462483/c-quick-way-to-invert-a-nullable-bool).

The accepted answer on the referenced question was correct *and better* than the current answer to the question as it now stands, with comments.  The OP wanted to know how to invert a nullable bool in C#.  The accepted answer was originally simply to invert the value (b = !b). The original answerer modified it within the 5 minute edit window due to some erroneous complaints that he'd failed to account for the case where the nullable had no value and some issues with what the OP really wanted when the nullable had no value.  As amended by the OPs comments, however, a simple negation of the nullable, which was the original answer, is **the** correct answer.  The current accepted answer, though it works, is really more complex than necessary and communicates a misconception about how assignments of nullables work.

Ordinarily I'd simply roll the edit back.  In this case I've asked that the answerer reinstate his original answer, but he apparently hasn't seen it or declined without response.

What's the right call in this case?  Edit the answer (and completely change the sense of it from it's current state, leaving it open to more abuse from people who don't get it) or contribute my own answer (same as the original) in contrast.  I'm leaning toward the former, but I wonder if there's anything I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post your own answer and vote the wrong answer down.
The answer is what it is now, and you left plenty of comments.

And there already is a better answer (from @Allen) now

Comment: Fortunately (or unfortunately) I had to go to a meeting and it got resolved before I was able to look at it again.